# How much does each engine on a Boeing 747 weigh?

Tags: boeing-747

The Boeing 747 weighs 404,600 lbs in total, but how much of that does each engine take up?

Comment: It really depends on the 747 variant. You should precise which variant you are talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boeing 747 can be operated with different types of engines (and in general a specific model has multiple models of engines compatible with it due to competition between different engine manufacturers). Here are some of the engines that are compatible with B747 and their weights:

- GE CF6-50: 8,825–9,047 lb
- Rolls Royce RB211-524G/H : 12,540–12,764 lb
- Pratt & Whitney PW4000-94: 9420 lb

So as you see, from model to model the engine weight might differ and all these engines have been used on B747 at some point.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_PW4000), the PW4000 variant used on the 747 (PW4000-94), only weighs 9420lbs. The heavier variant is used on the 777.

Comment: I was not aware of this, thanks for bringing it up,

Comment: @Eylul Sure thing! I am glad I could help.